# Why can't fresh windows install of metasploit-framework connect to database?

Tags: metasploit

It gives error on startup:
`Failed to connect to the database: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished`

and on db_status: `No database driver installed. Try 'gem install pg'.`

Comment: Maybe it's not that fresh. Have you tried manually removing all folders prior to fresh install?

Comment: I have tried removing the metasploit-framework folder installing again. Still have the same issue.

Comment: is database started? did you try the recommended command?

Comment: There are tons and tons of results when I google your error. Have you tried any of those fixes?